# How do I get a computer's programing name and static IP address using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
Public Function GetComputerName() As String
    Dim ComputerName As String
    ComputerName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
    Return ComputerName
End Function
```

Comment: We need more than just code - we need to see an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a detailed description of your goal, and the **exact error or problematic output** you're getting. See [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

**For PC name use:**

```
 My.Computer.Name
```

**For IP use:**

```
 Private Sub GetIPAddress()

 Dim strHostName As String 
 Dim strIPAddress As String

 strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()

 strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()


MessageBox.Show("Host Name: " & strHostName & "; IP Address: " & strIPAddress)

End Sub
```